# R: lag/lead filter and group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have large dataframe for more than 100 000 rows like this:

| time | team | match | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:05 | PSG | A | set |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:15 | Arsenal | D | take on |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:17 | Man City | C | take on |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:19 | Arsenal | D | shot |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:27 | PSG | F | take on |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:28 | Barcelona | S | take on |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:29 | Real Madrid | E | shot |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:30 | PSG | F | set |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:31 | PSG | F | shot |

I need to filter rows with type 'take on' which occurred 5 seconds before row type 'shot' with group by team.

So desired output

| time | team | match | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:15 | Arsenal | D | take on |
| 2023-01-15 13:19:27 | PSG | F | take on |

I've tried

```
library(dplyr)
data$time <- lubridate::as_datetime(data$time)

data %>%
     group_by(team, match) %>%
     filter(type == "take on",
            (time - lead(time, order_by=team)) <= 5 &
            lead(events, order_by=team) == "shot")
```

But get the same output regardless which lead value I choose - 5, 10, 15 etc. It means there is something wrong in this method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any`, filter on 'take_on' and grab the 'shot' that are within the 5-second range, i.e.

```
data %>%
     arrange(team, time) %>%
     group_by(team) %>%
     filter(type == 'take on' & any(type == 'shot' & time <= time + 5))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Groups:   team [2]
  time                team    match type   
  <dttm>              <chr>   <chr> <chr>  
1 2023-01-15 13:19:15 Arsenal D     take on
2 2023-01-15 13:19:27 PSG     F     take on
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using `lead()`. To make it work with must first filter out all rows that are neither `"shot"` nor `"take on"`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(type %in% c("shot", "take on")) %>% 
  group_by(team, match) %>%
  filter(type == "take on",
         (time - lead(time)) <= 5,
          lead(type == "shot"))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#> # Groups:   team, match [2]
#>   time                team    match type   
#>   <dttm>              <chr>   <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 2023-01-15 13:19:15 Arsenal D     take on
#> 2 2023-01-15 13:19:27 PSG     F     take on
```

Data from OP

```r
data <- tribble(~time, ~team, ~match, ~type,
  
  "2023-01-15 13:19:05",  "PSG"        , "A", "set",      
  "2023-01-15 13:19:15",  "Arsenal"    , "D", "take on",
  "2023-01-15 13:19:17",  "Man City"   , "C", "take on",  
  "2023-01-15 13:19:19",  "Arsenal"    , "D", "shot",    
  "2023-01-15 13:19:27",  "PSG"        , "F", "take on", 
  "2023-01-15 13:19:28",  "Barcelona"  , "S", "take on",  
  "2023-01-15 13:19:29",  "Real Madrid", "E", "shot",     
  "2023-01-15 13:19:30",  "PSG"        , "F", "set",     
  "2023-01-15 13:19:31",  "PSG"        , "F", "shot"
)
  
data$time <- lubridate::as_datetime(data$time)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>